# How to insert form data into MySQL database table

Tags: php, mysql, insert

So I have this registration script:

The HTML:

```
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
    <label>Username:</label> <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
    <label>Password:</label> <input type="text" name="password" /><br />

    <label>Gender:</label>
    <select name="gender">
      <optgroup label="genderset">
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
        <option value="Hermaphrodite">Hermaphrodite</option>
        <option value="Not Sure!!!">Not Sure!!!</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select><br />
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

The PHP/SQL:

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO registration_info (username, password, gender) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$gender')
")  

?>
```

The problem is, the username and password gets inserted into the "registration_info" table just fine. But the Gender input from the select drop down menu doesn't. Can some one tell me how to fix this, thanks.

Comment: Never, ever, ever put form parameters into a query like that. Try Bind parameters (http://uk.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead

Comment: Yeah, I know this isn't at all secure, I am just practicing the basic, this script will never go on line :)

Comment: You may want to do a print_r($_POST) and see how the data is coming in to your script, will make it easie to debug.

Comment: dude, it works.  I just copied and pasted your script and did a var_dump of $_POST, it works just fine!  Might wanna test it yourself again!

Comment: Can you tell us the schema for table 'registration_info'? Especially what is the type for column 'gender'?

Answer (score 1):

check the datatype in the database, there could be a mismatch

Answer (score 1):

*Try this one if you have taken gender field as integer in the database*

```
<select name="gender">
  <optgroup label="genderset">
    <option value="1">Male</option>
    <option value="2">Female</option>
    <option value="3">Hermaphrodite</option>
    <option value="4">Not Sure!!!</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

*Then selected value is inserted into the database*

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give any of the options a value, so only an empty string gets inserted.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to do that when I rewrote the script here, in the original I do have values inside each option, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value attribute in list items in the HTML.

e.g.

```
<option value="Male">Male</option>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to do that when I rewrote the script here, in the original I do have values inside each option, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. <s>You have no `password` input here.</s>
2. <s>Your `gender` `select box`'s options have no values.</s>
3. Use [`mysql_escape_string`](http://pl.php.net/manual/pl/function.mysql-escape-string.php) at least

   $username = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);

or parse to `int` if you except `int` value.

```
$id = (int) $_POST['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

<?php
  echo var_dump($_POST['gender']);
?>

Does that tell you anything? Maybe your gender datatype (in your table) is not compatible with what you put into it? Perhaps it's an ENUM('M','F') for example.

Answer (score -1):

Create a variable say, $gend in the php file.

Then,

$gend=$_POST['gender'];

Then, proceed with:

mysql_query("INSERT INTO registration_info (username, password, gender) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$gend')
") ;

Try this.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It is no different than the OP already did in the provided code.

Answer (score -1):

There are two option for your question :-

```
1) If you want to store the gender value in your database then change the datatype of gender field to varchar and then try again

2) If your gender field is integer in database then you have to make changes in select option value like following 

<select name="gender">
  <optgroup label="genderset">
    <option value="1">Male</option>
    <option value="2">Female</option>
    <option value="3">Hermaphrodite</option>
    <option value="4">Not Sure!!!</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Second option is same as @sneha suggestion.

It may help you.